# How do I get a list of config options that a charm has?

Tags: juju

I tried to test a charm but it had configuration options and I wasn't aware of them. Short of [browsing the charm itself](http://charms.kapilt.com/~george-edison55/oneiric/statusnet/config) how can I see what config options a charm has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`juju get` and then the charm name will tell you what config options it has and what the current value is, if any.

```
jorge@lowgirl:~/src/oneiric$ juju get statusnet
charm: local:oneiric/statusnet-1
service: statusnet
settings:
    email:
        description: The email address of the administrator (cannot be changed)
        type: string
        value: -Not set-
    nickname:
        description: The nickname for the administrator (cannot be changed)
        type: string
        value: -Not set-
    password:
        description: The password for the administrator
        type: string
        value: -Not set-
    title:
        description: The name of the site
        type: string
        value: Untitled
```

`juju set` will then pass along the config, like so:

```
juju set statusnet email="whatever@example.com" nickname="jorge" password="whatever"
```

Each command has corresponding documentation:

- `juju get --help`
- `juju set --help`